# Folder /usr/lib/wsl is missing in WSL 2

Tags: windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, nvidia

I've been encountering difficulties getting my Nvidia GPU to function within WSL 2. While researching solutions, I noticed that many discussions refer to a "wsl" folder in "/usr/lib" containing the necessary libraries and the "nvidia-smi" utility. However, in my case, the there isn't any "wsl" folder in "usr/lib".

I have the nvidia driver installed in Windows and the libraries and nvidia-smi are present in the lxss folder.

Despite this, I'm still facing issues. I'm curious about what might be causing this problem and would appreciate any insights or suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: My Ubuntu distribution does contain this folder. What is your distribution? Perhaps you could remove it and re-get from the Windows Store.

Comment: I have Debian. And i have tried reinstalling it. I even tried installing Ubuntu, but with no succes.

Comment: I wonder if you have a problem with WSL. Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: I ran the commands from both links. Sfc found a couple of corrupt file and repaired them successfully. After a restart i re-downloaded Ubuntu from MS Store but wsl folder is still not there.

Comment: I found the problem, it was my .wslconfig file. It had a the line "gpuSupport=false". I guess I experimented with the file and forgot about it :(. Thank you for the suggestions.